# Consecrated to the relief of

Tags: meaning

Is the following sentence grammatical?

> His life was consecrated to the relief of suffering.

To me it doesn't appear.

Comment: It's fine. Why do you have a problem? Have you used a dictionary?

Comment: Some dictionaries indeed list "consecrate" as synonym to "devote" and "dedicate", but I would've used "dedicated" or "devoted", and active voice instead of passive - "he devoted his life to the relief of suffering". I don't remember ever seeing "consecrate" used with this meaning. Grammatically, though, your sentence is fine.

Comment: Kreiri, it's very common, as a brief Google search would have revealed.

Answer (score 2):

This sentence is grammatical.

'Consecrated to' means 'dedicated to' or 'devoted to', however it has more of a spiritual or religious connotation. It suggests that there was a spiritual motivation to the dedication of his life to the relief of suffering.

The sentence is in the passive voice. It means nearly the same thing as

> He consecrated his life to the relief of suffering.

The difference is that the passive voice gives us the sense that the consecration happened in the past and is ongoing. His life was and is still consecrated to the relief of suffering. It also might mean that he didn't choose to dedicate his life to the relief of suffering, but that the choice was made for him. The feeling that the choice was made for him strengthens the sense of spiritual origin for the consecration. He might have been spiritually called to consecrate his life to the relief of suffering rather than just deciding one day to consecrate it to the relief of suffering.